Ordinal addition with limit ordinals, as in Kunen.
This definition of ordinal adddition is taken from Kenneth Kunens "Set Theory: An Introduction to Independence Proofs":
$\alpha + \beta = \text{type}(\alpha \times \{0\} \cup \beta \times \{1\},R)$ where
$$
R = \{ \langle \langle \xi,0 \rangle,\langle \eta,0 \rangle \rangle : \xi < \eta < \alpha\} \cup \{ \langle \langle \xi,1 \rangle, \langle \eta,1 \rangle \rangle : \xi < \eta < \beta \} \cup \left[(\alpha \times \{0\}) \times (\beta \times \{1\})\right].
$$
Now, lemma 7.18.(5) gives us that if $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, then $\alpha + \beta = \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi < \beta\}$. I am a bit confused as to how to prove this using the definition given above. I am not quite comfortable with ordinals yet, and would be happy for hints/suggestions/full solutions.
Remark: Note that I am interested in proving this from Kunens definition; so unless I am mistaken, I don't want a proof in terms of induction, of which I have already seen (unless there is some way to apply induction in the context of this definition of ordinal addition).
Remark 2: I am quite comfortable with the definition itself, but I am probably missing some piece for how to apply it here. For example, do I have to consider the cases when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, and when $\alpha$ is a successor ordinal, separately?

This question also appears in Pinter, Set Theory, Exercise 9.3, 12 b). Pinter is easy to find online. If you use the path suggested by Pinter, then you will need to prove the following as pre-requisites (maybe these are also done in Kunen, I don't know):
A. $\alpha = \alpha + \emptyset$. Exercises 9.2, #8. Easy to prove.
B. $\alpha +(\beta + \gamma)=(\alpha + \beta)+ \gamma$. Associativity. Theorem 9.9 i).
C. $\beta \ne \emptyset \implies \alpha \in \alpha + \beta$. Theorem 9.14 i).
D. $ \alpha \in \beta \implies \alpha + \delta = \beta$ for some $\delta \ne \emptyset$. Theorem 9.15.
E. $\alpha \underline\in \beta \implies \alpha + \delta = \beta$ for some $\delta$. Simple corollary of the above.
F. $ \alpha \in \beta \iff \gamma+ \alpha \in \gamma + \beta$. Theorem 9.16 i) and ii).
G. $\alpha \underline\in \alpha + \beta$. A simple corollary to A and C.
H. $\alpha + 1 = \alpha^+$. A proof for you.
I. $\alpha + \beta^+ = (\alpha + \beta)^+$. A simple corollary of H and B.
We will now prove $\beta$ is a limit ordinal implies $\alpha + \beta = \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$. Note that this proof does not directly use Kunen's definition, but it relies on results that have been created using this definition only (i.e. we have not used the traditional definition based on recursion).
Suppose $\beta$ is a limit ordinal.
Suppose $\gamma \in \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$.
Suppose $\alpha + \xi \underline\in \gamma$ for all $\xi \in \beta$. Then $\gamma$ is an upper bound of $\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$ and so $\sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\} \underline\in \gamma$, a contradiction. Hence $\gamma \in \alpha + \xi$ for some $\xi \in \beta$. By F. $\alpha + \xi \in \alpha + \beta$ so $\gamma \in \alpha + \beta$ and so $\sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\} \subseteq \alpha + \beta$.
Suppose $\gamma \in \alpha + \beta$. Suppose $\gamma \notin \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$. Suppose there is some $\xi \in \beta$ such that $\gamma \in \alpha + \xi$. Then $\gamma \in \delta$ for some $\delta \in \{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$. And so $\delta\underline\in \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$. Hence $\gamma \in \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$, a contradiction. Hence $\xi \in \beta \implies \gamma \notin \alpha + \xi$. That is, $\alpha + \xi \underline\in \gamma$. By G. $\alpha \underline\in \alpha + \xi$, so $\alpha \underline\in \gamma$. And so by E. $\alpha + \delta = \gamma$ for some ordinal $\delta$. Hence $\alpha + \delta \in \alpha + \beta$. So, by F. $\delta \in \beta$. And as $\beta$ is a limit ordinal, $\delta^+ \in \beta$. By I., $\alpha + \delta^+=(\alpha+\delta)^+$ and we know $\alpha + \delta \in (\alpha + \delta)^+$. So $\gamma = \alpha + \delta \in (\alpha + \delta)^+=\alpha + \delta^+$. Hence $\gamma \in \alpha + \zeta$ for some $\zeta \in \beta$, a contradiction. Hence $\gamma \in \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$ and $\alpha + \beta \subseteq \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$.
Hence $\alpha + \beta = \sup\{\alpha + \xi : \xi \in \beta\}$.
Grateful if anyone can tell me if there are any issues with this proof...
